# Cannot post variable from android client to php server

Tags: android, post, webserver, webservice-client, android-webservice

I develop an android code for transmit and received between android apps and PHP. The received part which is based on JSON, is properly working. I have tested by set variable manually in PHP code. However, when I have posted the variable from android to php, it cannot receive it. Anyone can tell me the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();


    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", <Your username here>));


    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(<Your URL to php file>);
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); // Execute Post to URL
        String st = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); // This is the result from php web
        Log.d(TK_Configuration.TAG, "In the try Loop" + st); // Still executing
        finalResult = st; // You should register a variable for finalResult;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TK_Configuration.TAG, "Connection error : " + e.toString());
    }
    return "OK";

}

protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    // After that, you will have final result and process to do with it here
    // Below is my simple code, please change it
    if(finalResult.equals("1")){
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.upload_bike_success), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(context, context.getResources().getString(R.string.upload_bike_fail), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    // End
}
```

Please try this, and one more point, you should use Gson library to decode JSON quickly to Java Object after you got JSON string from server.
Note: Replace TK_Configuration.TAG << by your TAG.

Comment: what is TK_Configuration tag ?

Comment: Error:(243, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing

Comment: Hi, I saw you have wrong request file http://www.oobac.com/app/insert-db.php << this file use to insert data to database? Right? If you want to get data from database, you use amir.php << Right?

Comment: Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Which line make the error "Error:(243, 2) error: reached end of file while parsing"? I am working with JSON php and JAVA android now. We can discuss via my skype "trantkhoi"

Answer (score 1):

you have commented this line it means you are not passing values from Android

```
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

remove comment from this line.

One more thing, you are passing `username` but from php you are trying to fetch value as `$user = $_POST['name'];`, both name must be same.

Comment: I modified $user = $_POST['username']; and uncomment httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs)); However, it does not work

Comment: try to print `username` in php code and check whether you are getting it or not.

Comment: should I echo $user in my php file? where I should see it in android or browser?

Comment: you should get it in android side as a response. print `result` variable in log or toast.

Comment: Log.d(result.toString(), "doInBackground: ");

Comment: 02-29 13:03:41.828 16241-16278/com.example.alan.mainactivity W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xad9e0740, error=EGL_SUCCESS
02-29 13:03:42.505 16241-16278/com.example.alan.mainactivity E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xac1a3b20
02-29 13:03:42.510 16241-16241/com.example.alan.mainactivity I/Choreographer: Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.